# how to use new line for BSD sed substitution

Tags: sed, newline

I have a sed command as follows:

```
sed -i 's/),(/),\n(/g' myfile
```

myfile is like this:

```
(237),(238)
```

The expected result is:

```
(237),
(238)
```

The actual result is:

```
(237),n(238)
```

I have tried many ways to write new line, but all failed. Is it possible to get the expected result?

I found that `GNU sed` works, but `BSD sed` not.

Answer (score 1):

for `BSD sed`, we can write new line as `$'\n'`, so the command should be:

```
/usr/bin/sed 's/),(/),\'$'\n''(/g' myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e 'G' -e 's/,\(.*\)\(.\)/,\2\1/' file
```

The `G` command will append the hold space to the pattern space, which in effect will, as the hold space is empty, append a newline. Pattern matching can re-arrange this to the desired result.